# How to add transparent text covert in single row covered all columns style is css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

[image]

I want create table look like this. i want to cover all row by status like this. Status will be suspended, close and open. when status is open then doesn't want to show the status. Give code in react if possible.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask SO isn't an ab initio coding service, but we are very happy to help with your code.

Comment: ok understood. If possible please help for code.

Comment: Please read and follow the advice in the how to ask post and also look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example SO isn't here to create code from scratch I'm afraid.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a div inside `<tr>`. However, it is not recommended.

```
<tr style={{position: 'relative'}}>
 <div style={
       {
        display: 'flex',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
        background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'
      }
 }>
   SUSPENDED
 </div>
 <td>cell 1</td>
 <td>cell 2</td>
 <td>cell 3</td>
</tr>
```

[image]